# Null or Zero values as the output when scripting in Databrick notebook

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-databricks

I'm creating a script that reads resume data and returns a score based on parameters that are significant in this case the `experience level`, `clearance`, `education`, and `skills`.

Right now, I'm working on just the `experience`, `clearance`, and `education` columns and **scores it based on a criterion I created which then multiplies a weight of .25 for each column**.

I've finished the script< but when I run it, **I get null or zero values as the output when a new score column is created for each parameter**. I double checked the resume dataset and variable names and if I'm correctly scoring the values, but I still get null values as the output.

The overall gist of the code is:

1. First I keep only the number of the years of experience,
2. then I set the score criteria for each the keys, keys are what I will be looking for in the rows and the values are the scores I'm setting.
3. After that I calculate the scores to apply it in each column by calling it as a function and
4. then outputting a total score by adding up all the score columns.

```
weight = 0.25

def extract_years(exp):
    if exp is None:
        return 0
    
    exp_str = str(exp)
    pattern = r'(\d+)'
    matches = re.findall(pattern, exp_str)
    if len(matches) > 0:
        return int(matches[0])
    else:
        return 0
    
experience_criteria = {
    '0': 0,
    '2': 25,
    '5': 50,
    '8': 75,
    '10': 100,
    'Mgr/Director': 100
}

education_criteria = {
    'None': 0,
    'Certification': 20,
    'High School or Equivalent': 20,
    'Associate': 40,
    'Bachelors': 60,
    'Masters': 80,
    'Doctorate': 100
}

clearance_criteria = {
    'None': 0,
    'Public': 25,
    'Secret': 50,
    'Top Secret': 75,
    'Top Secret/SCI': 100,
    'Top Secret/Poly': 100,
    'Top Secret/FSP': 100
}

def calculate_experience_score(exp):
    exp_str = str(exp)
    print("Experience:", exp_str)
    score = experience_criteria.get(exp_str, 0)
    print("Experience Score:", score)
    return score

def calculate_education_score(education):
    education_str = str(education)
    print("Education:", education_str)
    score = education_criteria.get(education_str, 0)
    print("Education Score:", score)
    return score

def calculate_clearance_score(clearance):
    clearance_str = str(clearance)
    print("Clearance:", clearance_str)
    score = clearance_criteria.get(clearance_str, 0)
    print("Clearance Score:", score)
    return score

extract_years_udf = udf(extract_years, IntegerType())

calculate_experience_score_udf = udf(calculate_experience_score, DoubleType())
calculate_education_score_udf = udf(calculate_education_score, DoubleType())
calculate_clearance_score_udf = udf(calculate_clearance_score, DoubleType())

# Apply the scoring functions and assign the scores to the respective columns
df_resume = df_resume.withColumn("experience", extract_years_udf(col("experience").cast(StringType())))
df_resume = df_resume.withColumn("ExperienceScore", when(col("experience").isNotNull(), calculate_experience_score_udf(col("experience"))) * weight)
df_resume = df_resume.withColumn("EducationScore", when(col("education").isNotNull(), calculate_education_score_udf(col("education"))) * weight)
df_resume = df_resume.withColumn("ClearanceScore", when(col("clearance").isNotNull(), calculate_clearance_score_udf(col("clearance"))) * weight)

df_resume = df_resume.withColumn("TotalScore", col("ExperienceScore") + col("EducationScore") + col("ClearanceScore"))

display(df_resume)
```

I don't understand why I'm getting no output for the values, could someone explain to me on what I need to change or try in order to get the results I would like.

I'm scripting on `Azure Databrick notebook` in `pySparks` since the Pandas module isn't supported in the notebook.

I'm expecting an output scoring results for the significant columns that will be used to calculate total score for each resume as I explained above.

I changed up the code, I tried on `Juypter notebook` and used the regular pandas module and it worked fine. I ran out of ideas of what it could be.

Answer (score 0):

Modify these parts of your code as below.

```
def extract_years(exp):
    if exp is  None:
        return  0
    elif exp == 'Mgr/Director':
        return exp
        
    exp_str = str(exp)
    pattern = r'(\d+)'
    matches = re.findall(pattern, exp_str)
    if  len(matches) > 0:
        return  str(int(matches[0]))
    else:
        return  str(0)
    
extract_years_udf = udf(extract_years, StringType())
```

Add condition for the experience `Mgr/Director` and return the value as **string**, then register udf with return type **StringType()**.

Next, change the return type of all udf to **IntegerType()** as below.

```
calculate_experience_score_udf = udf(calculate_experience_score, IntegerType())
calculate_education_score_udf = udf(calculate_education_score, IntegerType())
calculate_clearance_score_udf = udf(calculate_clearance_score, IntegerType())
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hey, thank you for responding, I changed those lines of codes and got some correct output for some rows, but the experience column becomes null, and I get null values for the total score column. Would I have to change the type somewhere else?

Comment: ok some records returning float values in your sample data. So return them as `return float(score)` and keep all udf return type as it is `DoubleType()`

Comment: So I did that but the experience column goes null for all the rows which I guess in return makes the experience score column null and the total score column null. Another thing is that when I change the extract years UDF to be either String Type or Integer Type it makes the experience columns zero but I get a value for total score column. Why is that?

Comment: Still zero can be added with other column values and gets total score. All you need to do is matching the return type of functions to udf register datatype.

Comment: I thought I already did that when I called the UDFs and applied it in the columns. Do I need to use the function isin() to use the dictionary and the UDFs? How would that work?

Comment: No you already returning 0 if the attribute does not present in dictionary. Do all your function return type to float.And provide your sample input data.